# Unsubscribe to single Keyword in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Scenario- We would like to create a Custom keyword (Lets Call - MCOUT) in Mobile-connect to "Opt-in" the subscribers, but if the subscriber wants "Opt-Out" of only "MCOUT" Keyword but not all communications from the company.

Is there a way to unsubscribe to that particular keyword only??

If there is no way of doing that, can someone shed some light on how to handle above scenario.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

It used to be the case that if someone was subscribed to multiple keywords and sent a stop message, they would get an auto response asking which keywords they would like to unsubscribe from. See the below example.

[image: Screenshot of message conversation]

I can't find any documentation to back this up as still being the case though.

Comment: Is it "StopIn" keyword or just "Stop" - we didn't try StopIn keyword before

Comment: Apologies - I should have clarified that stopln was a custom stop keyword that I had created - see here on how to create one: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_create_a_custom_stop_keyword.htm&type=5
I believe 'stop' is a global unsubscribe keyword - you can find the full list here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_default_stop_keywords.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the text as follows:

"Access the Salesforce support article by following this link: [Salesforce Support Article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381673&type=1).

Alternatively, you may consider using a keyword-based approach. You can utilize AMPScript or SSJS to create a response text triggered by a specific keyword. This response text can be used to update consent or subscription preferences in the Master Data Extension (MasterDE) or Customer Relationship Management (CRM) system while also suppressing further communications to the recipient."